# how to disable DST_METRIC_READ_ONLY kernel 3.0.26

Tags: c, network-programming, linux-kernel, ipv6, kernel

In net/include/dst.h the flag DST_METRICS_READ_ONLY is set on the _metric member of struct dst. But I don't want that that structure be read only. How to disable that flag.

thanks in advance

Comment: I want somebody say something before reducing the reputation. I have some five questions unanswered related to this issue. People concerning reducing the reputation can try to answer those qns.

Comment: DST_METRIC_READ_ONLY does not exist in kernel source files...kernel 3.0.26 include/net/dst.h (http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0.26/include/net/dst.h).

Comment: @A.G.: I am sorry. I did a spelling mistake. its DST_METRICS_READ_ONLY not DST_METRIC_READ_ONLY

Answer (score 1):

*dst->_metrics* is set to *DST_METRICS_READ_ONLY* only if function *dst_init_metrics()* is called with **its parameter read_only set to true**. So if yo want to make sure to not enable this read-only flag, patch your kernel to use false everywhere dst_init_metrics is called.